# I cannot update labels with info retrieved from API in kivy python

Tags: asynchronous, kivy

I have 3 labels in kv file. When retrieve info from the internet the labels are not updated.
How to solve this issue?
I mention that the info are correctly retrieved from the API, but the text into the labels are not updated with those values.
My code is below:
'''

```
import asyncio
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import async_runTouchApp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from spring import Spring


class MyDacia(FloatLayout):
    mileage = StringProperty()
    battLevel = StringProperty()
    autonomy = StringProperty()

    async def initializare(self):
        mySpring=Spring()
        await mySpring.initialize()
        self.autonomy= str(mySpring.getAutonomy())
        self.battLevel = str(mySpring.getBattLevel())
        self.mileage = str(mySpring.getCarMileage())
        #self.add_widget(Label(text=self.mileage+" km"))
        #print(f"Autonomie: {self.autonomy}")
         


      
class MyDaciaApp(App):
    
    
    
    def build(self):
    
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      loop.run_until_complete(MyDacia.initializare(self=MyDacia()))
      loop.close
      return MyDacia()
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        MyDaciaApp().run()
    '''
```

Comment: I've solved the problem adding an "update" button, that update de label values with the data retrieved previously. This update function is a normal one, not an asynchronous one, because the data were already retrieved from the internet. I know is not an elegant solution but it works for me.